# Not able to add Intent in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, android-intent, navigation

I want to add intent to different values of the navigation drawer but i am getting an error

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tanis.myapplication/com.example.tanis.myapplication.MenuItems.Home}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.tanis.myapplication.MenuItems.Home cannot be cast to android.app.Activity

please help

## Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.tanis.myapplication">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="WebTechiq"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".Splash"
            android:label="WebTechniQ">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MenuItems.Registration"
            android:label="Registration"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MenuItems.Home"
            android:label="Home"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

## Home.java

```
package com.example.tanis.myapplication.MenuItems;

/**
 * Created by tanis on 27-06-2018.
 */

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.tanis.myapplication.Adapters.CardItemString;
import com.example.tanis.myapplication.Adapters.CardPagerAdapterS;
import com.example.tanis.myapplication.Adapters.ViewPagerAdapter;
import com.example.tanis.myapplication.R;
import com.example.tanis.myapplication.Services.website_designing;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Home extends Fragment {


    ViewPager mViewPager;
    CardPagerAdapterS mCardAdapter;
    ShadowTransformer mCardShadowTransformer;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    String titlesText[] = {" Website Design", " Digital Marketing", " Domain Registration", "Graphics Design", " Mobile Apps", " Server Hosting",
            " Software Development", " Content Marketing", " Security (SSl)"};
    String detailsArray[] = {
            "Your website is your digital home. We create, design, redesign, develop, improvise, and implement. We make beautiful websites",
            "We help your business reach potential customers on every possible digital device through all possible media channels    ",
            "To  launch  your  website  the  first  thing  you  need  is  the  domain  name.  You  can  choose  your  domain  name  with  us  here  ",
            "We  generate  creative  solutions  and  can  create  a  wide  range  of  graphic  for  your  clients  which  match  their  business         ",
            "We are mobile. And we make you mobile. We make responsive websites and mobile apps which compliment your business       ",
            "When  you  are  hosting  your     website  in  the  India  you   will  benefit  from  a      higher  ping  rate  and   lowest             latency              ",
            "Our team is competent at coding web apps with keen attention to detail & intuitive functionality that is high on design & creativity",
            "Content  is  the  heart  of  your  digital  presence. We  create  the right            content  with  the  right  focus   for   your  business",
            "Secure your site with the world's leading   provider of online security and get    these exclusive features at no added   cost",
    };
    int[] images = {R.drawable.website_design, R.drawable.digita, R.drawable.domain_registration, R.drawable.gric,
            R.drawable.mob, R.drawable.server, R.drawable.software_development, R.drawable.ontent, R.drawable.ssl};
    private Context context;


    public Home() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment.
     *
     * @return A new instance of fragment FragmentAction.
     */


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false);
        TextView txt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView12);
        txt.setText("\u25BA Creative & Dedicated Team");
        TextView txt1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView13);
        txt1.setText("\u25BA Affordable Cost");
        TextView txt2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView14);
        txt2.setText("\u25BA Maintain Long Relationship");
        TextView txt3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView15);
        txt3.setText("\u25BA Timely Deliverly ");

        context = this.getContext();

        Button b = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button7);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), website_designing.class);
            }
        });


        mViewPager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.viewpager1);

        mCardAdapter = new CardPagerAdapterS();


        for (int i = 0; i < titlesText.length; i++) {

            mCardAdapter.addCardItemS(new CardItemString(titlesText[i], detailsArray[i], images[i]));
        }

        mCardShadowTransformer = new ShadowTransformer(mViewPager, mCardAdapter);

        mViewPager.setAdapter(mCardAdapter);
        mViewPager.setPageTransformer(false, mCardShadowTransformer);
        mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);


        viewPager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this.getContext());
        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Mytime(), 2000, 4000);


        FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton = (FloatingActionButton) v.findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton);
        floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), Registration.class));
            }
        });


        return v;

    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


    }

    public class Mytime extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
                    } else if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 1) {
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);

                    } else if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 2) {
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(3);

                    } else if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 3) {
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(4);

                    } else {
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you update your question with AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: I have updated the menifest

Comment: Please read basic of Android development first.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error because of following lines:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MenuItems.Home"
        android:label="Home"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

You cannot add a Fragment(Your `Home` class extends `Fragment`) in `AndroidManifest.xml`. You need an `Activity` to load this Fragment. Follow [official guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments) for proper usage of Fragment.

Answer (score 0):

> no fragments can be instantiate through Manifest.. You can only use
>   AppCompatActivity for extending.there is no need to instantiate a Fragment in Manifest

For that you should change

```
public class Home extends AppCompatActivity {.....}
```

Now Manifest will never show any error
if you want to call a fragment while an event occurs you should use another methode

if you want to Display a fragment,the below code will help you

Main Activity

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    Button bd;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        bd=(Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);


        bd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

                BlankFragment fragmentFeaturedNews = new BlankFragment();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.framelayout, fragmentFeaturedNews);

                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        });



    }
}
```

main xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.stacktest.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/submit"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:text="fetch Fragments"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/framelayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/submit"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp">
    </FrameLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```